# Which is the correct gerund clause? 'People's killing animals', or 'People killing animals ... '?

Tags: gerunds, possessives

Which is the correct gerund clause that should be used here?

1. People killing animals is a bad thing.. or
2. People'**s** killing animals is a bad thing..
3. John being late is a bit inconvenient. or
4. John'**s** being late is a bit inconvenient.

(At the beginning of sentence,Is the subject before the gerund expressed as a possessive noun?)

Comment: It would be more interesting to reply if you added your own guesses and thoughts to the question.

Comment: I feel like "humans killing animals" is better than "people".

Answer (score 3):

> John being late is a bit inconvenient.
>
> John's being late is a bit inconvenient.

Both of these sentences are correct. It's a bit easier to show what happens in sentences like this if we use pronouns:

- Him being late really annoys me
- His being late really annoys me.

Gerund-participle clauses like this are non-finite. This means that we can't use them as a sentence on their own:

- *His being late. (wrong)

Non-finite clauses in English don't usually use subject pronouns (*nominative pronouns*) like *I*, *she* or *he* for example. With gerund-particilple clauses, accusative pronouns (*me, you, him* ... ) and genitive, possessive  pronouns (my, her, his ... ) are fine:

- *I don't like he being late. (wrong)
- I don't like him being late.
- I don't like his being late.

Other nouns like *John* or *people* don't have nominative or accusative case, so we can use them as subjects without changing them:

- I don't like John being late.
- I don't like people being late.

But these other nouns *do* have a genitive form *John's* and *people's*. Like we did with the pronouns we can use genitive nouns as subjects in gerund-participial clauses like this:

- I don't like John's being late.
- I don't like people's being late. (see note below)

*HOWEVER* ...

The first example there with *John's* is perfectly normal. The second example with *people's* is a bit strange. It's not ungrammatical - it just feels odd. It feels awkward. *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* explains that genitive subjects like this are usually singular, and are also usually short (2002; p. 1192). If the subject is plural, or if it is several words, we prefer not to use the genitive at all:

- I don't like my father-in-law's new wife's being late. (awkward)
- I don't like women's being given worse pay than men. (very awkward)

So, to answer the Original Poster's question, all four of the original examples are grammatical. However, *People's killing animals* is a bit strange, and speakers don't usually use plural genitive nouns as Subjects.

Hope this helps!

**Note**
Plural genitive nouns are perfectly fine in most situations. Subjects of gerund participle clauses are unusual because we don't usually use plural genitives here.

**Reference**
*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* Huddleston & Pullum, 2002 (p. 1192-3)

Comment: 'It was not a question for them being able to get a car'  in this statement did we use  gerund

Comment: @pramod Yes, but I think it would be better to use a comma here after *them*. The sentence is called an *extraposition*. This means that we use *it* as the grammar subject, and move the *meaning*-subject to the end. The sentence means '***Being able to get a car** was not a question for them*'.

Comment: @pramod Notice that the gerund-participal here doesn't have a subject that we can see. But we can still understand it. We could write *It was not a question for them, **their** being able to get a car*.

Comment: @pramod I don't understand what you mean ...

Comment: What is the Meaning of 'being able to get a car' here. Is it complete with scene

Comment: @pramod The sentence means that they had no money. So they didn't even think about the question *Are we able to get a car*?  ---> It was not a question for them 'were they able to get a car' --> Gerund  ---> It was not a question for them *their being able to get a car*

Comment: @pramod Is that clearer?

Comment: I got clarity on the sentence. But I would like to know whether the gerund alone have complete sense or not

Comment: @pramod You mean without *their* ?

Comment: ' l am being able to get a car'.  Is there gerund in this sentence? In my opinion, it is just a present progressive, isn't it?

Comment: @pramod People normally use the word *gerund* when the *ing* verb is behaving like a noun. For example if it is part of the subject or object of a sentence. In your example it isn't. It is just part of the main verb phrase. It's just an example of the present continuous. However, your sentence is not very good because we - generally - only use the present continuous with actions. *being able to* is not an action, it's a situation.

Comment: Yes. I was about to say it. So, in ' Being busy, i can't meet you'. Till now, i have been thinking that the above sentence have gerund . am i right

Comment: @pramod People would probably say that was a participle. However some modern grammars don't like to use the words *gerund* and *participle*. They prefer to have one name for botht things - they call them *gerund-participles*. So, yes, your sentence does have a gerund-participal!! :)

Comment: Okay, ' their being able to get a car'  is it stands alone. Is it a complete sentence

Comment: @pramod No, it isn't.

Comment: 'It was not a question for them being able to get a car' could you split the sentence into phrase and clause , subject and verb and analyze it, please ?

Comment: @pramod Sorry, I'm writing another post at the moment :)