# Does this sentence contain a gerund?

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses, present-participles

In my opinion, gerund are verbs in noun form and they can be the subject, object or complement of a sentence.

If i have understood correctly, could you please let me know whether the following sentence contains gerund or not. If so, how we can signifies it as a gerund

> It was not a question of them being able to get a car.

Please analyze the above sentence by dividing into clauses, phrases as well as subject,object and verb.

Comment: This is not quite idiomatic. *A question **for** X* means that it is a question which X must answer; *a question **of** X* means that it is X which is questionable. Do you mean "It was not a question (for them) **of** being able to get a car?" or "It was not a question [for somebody unspecified] **of** them being able to get a car"?

Comment: @StoneyB   The sentence is quoted verbatim from Charlie and the Chocolate factory. Here them represents a family

Comment: From the book? The closest I find is "There wasn't any question **of** them being able to buy a better house". The only instance of this sentence Google finds is--this question!

Comment: For reference: This question first appeared [in the comments on another answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/37280/which-is-the-correct-gerund-clause-peoples-killing-animals-or-people-killi/37283#comment69083_37283).

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check it once

Answer (score 2):

Stoney is correct. "It was not a question for them being able to get a car" is not acceptable English. If it really did appear in a book, then the publishers need to find new editors/proofreaders.

In  "It was not a question of them being able to get a car", 'being' is a gerund; it is a form of the verb, but has some noun-like qualities. This is why some purists would prefer 'their' to 'them'.

Comment: Could you please let me know  what type of noun-like qualities it has ? Because, I can't understand how it is a gerund. Are the following sentences are equal
1. were you able to buy a car ?
2. being able to buy a car

Answer (score 1):

> It was not a question of them **being** able to get a car.

Yes. It's a gerund. Its subject is **them**.

In English, sometimes it's hard or perhaps impossible to say whether the **-ing** form of a verb is a present participle or a gerund. In this sentence, one could argue that **being** is a participle modifying **them**. But I think it's clear that the question is about whether "they" *could get the car*, not simply about "them".

There is also another way to indicate the subject of a gerund, and that's to put the subject into the possessive case:

> It was not a question of **their** being able to get a car.

The whole clause, whether you word it "them being able to get a car" or "their being able to get a car", is the object of the preposition **of**. So, the clause is functioning as a big noun. This is the main thing gerunds do: they enable you to package up a verb, complete with its own subject and predicate, and treat it as a noun in a larger sentence.

"A question of them being able to get a car" is the subject-complement of "It".

The main verb is "was". The main subject is "It".